# Assembler IDE with a specific feature

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I recently delved into assembly and toyed with emu8086 a bit. I am having a lot of fun and learning quite a bit. 
However I really do miss one thing, It would be SO awesome if I could see ALL register contents AS I WRITE, before I emulate or compile. Does any assembly IDE offer this functionality?
I would prefer if I could write also 8086 assembly with NASM syntax in it, but any general x86 assembly that lifts the burden of keeping track of registers in my head would be a godsend and also highly efficient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have thought this through. Roughly speaking, if you could know the value of the registers you wouldn't need a program. Register values change based on input and other things, and also are not guaranteed to be the same at the same point in the code at different times. Think of a loop variable. What value do you want displayed?

```
    call get_int ; this function returns a number entered by the user in eax
    ; so, what's the value of eax here that your IDE should print?
    ; okay let's multiply it by 10 using addition in a loop
    mov edx, eax
    mov ecx, 9   ; ecx is 9 here, no problem
addloop:
    add eax, edx ; but what's the value of eax here?
    dec ecx      ; or ecx here?
    jnz addloop
    ; what's the result in eax?
```

Comment: Shame on me! You are right.Actually loop would not be that much of a problem, one could just interpret the whole loop as one instruction in the dynamic interpreter and that would still be very very useful. Much worse would be some unorderly jump back in code while intentionally not saving registers. Jumping around like that would mess the interpreter much more and make it useless.